# Travel to Portugal from Cologne, Germany

Tags: trains, germany, transportation, portugal

I am planning to travel to Portugal from Germany. I think everyone will suggest to travel by air. But I am interested to know, what are the other possibilities to travel to Lisbon or Porto from Cologne (Köln),Germany instead of Aeroplane. What can be approximate expenses?

Is there any direct train communication system from Germany to Portugal?

Comment: http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/ will show you possible routes by train. It seems you can make it in about 26 hours, changing trains twice.

Comment: Which possibility do you not have? The only thing coming to my mind is that it may be difficult to find a ferry connection. Except for that, you may go by train, bus, car, hitch-hike, bicycle or foot.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i am requesting for exact route suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried rome2rio?

Comment: Note that HAFAS, that bahn.de is based on, is incomplete in Spain and possibly Portugal.  Do compare with renfe.es and the Portuguese railways.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo [By boat from Rotterdam](http://www.langsamreisen.de/en/freightertravel/europe/portugal/).

Comment: This is, frankly, an off-topic request for us to create a travel itinerary for you (WANTA Debate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are direct bus connections from Cologne to Lisbon and Porto. It takes more or less 33 hours. A single ticket cost ~ 140 EUR. YOu can check schedules and prices via [busradar](https://www.busradar.com/).

It is also quite straightforward to do the journey by train. The fastest routes goes as follows. Travel from Cologne to Paris Nord. Take a metro to Paris Montparnasse and from there a TGV to Irun. In Irun you can board then the night train to Lisbon. If you want to go to Porto, get out at Coimbra and proceed from there to Porto. Prices depend on on the comfort, the date of travel and how long you book in advance. You can use [loco2](http://www.loco2.com) to make a price simulation. Check separately for Cologne - Paris and Paris - Lisbon.

Other train routes are possible. The [Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/Portugal.htm) has more details on this. They may be interesting if you want to stop somewhere en route.

Answer (score 4):

You could follow one of the Camino routes from Köln to Santiago de Compostela and then south to Lisbon. It can be done on foot or by bicycle. Might take a few months though. You can find lots of information online on the costs of hostels etc. on the routes.

Comment: Why is an answer *you can walk or bike in a few months* upvoted when the question is about trains?  This answer is completely unhelpful.

Comment: @gerrit the answer may well be helpful to others contemplating such a journey - SE answers are intended to be of long term usefulness, and not merely the OP. Not everyone is aware of the Camino today nor of the historical significance to the Iberian peninsula.

Comment: I seriously doubt that anyone who starts out with "I need to go to Portugal" ends up walking or biking from Germany. People do walk or bike that, but then they start at the other end: "I want to go biking for 4 weeks or walking for 4 months, where shall I go?", so I think this answer is not useful either for the OP, or for others (like me) reaching this question along other ways.

Comment: Yes, your downvote speaks for itself. I, for one, plan to do the trip, though probably from Portugal or the classic French route.

Comment: If you plan to do the trip, you wouldn't start from the question asked here.